# Full space occupied by the file system

Tags: linux, filesystems, posix

How can I find how much space the file system actually occupies on the block device, when the file system does not cover the whole partitions?

Consider the basic example to demonstrate the core problem:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=20480 of=something.img

losetup -f $PWD/something.img

mke2fs /dev/loop0

mount /dev/loop0 /mnt
```

But the `df -k /mnt` gives this output:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0         19827   172     18631   1% /mnt
```

I have created a device of precisely 2048KB, but the `statvfs()` syscall (and similarly the `df` as displayed above) reports that file system takes only 19827KB.

It seems that that `statvfs()` reports only the blocks which are usable for the user, but doesn't report the full actual size of the file system.

So far, I could find only a ext2/3/4-specific *hacky* *solution*: `tune2fs -l /dev/loop0 | grep 'Block count:'` or `dumpe2fs -h /dev/loop0 | grep 'Block count:'`.  A little bit more cleaner is to use the `libext2fs` library (part of `e2fprogs` package) to read the superblock, but I would much prefer a file-system neutral syscall, if it is available.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a POSIX syscall to retrieve device level information, I believe there are none.

For file system level information [portable] calls, as far as I know, you'll be able to retrieve the total number of `data blocks`, but not the remaining *overhead* (such as `inode tables` etc).

.

## The Problem

`statvfs(2)` and `fstatvfs(2)` will retrieve the "usable" (aka `data blocks`) file system level information (eg, `vfat`, `ext2`, `ext3` ...), not the underlying device level information (eg, `/dev/loop0`, `/dev/sda`, ...).

.

## A [partial / possible] Non-portable Solution

> [**EDIT 3**]: Not what OP is looking for (this is device level
>   information only and does not cover the case where the file system
>   does not map the entire device size).

Under Linux (assuming a relatively recent kernel version), you can use `ioctl(2)` to retrieve the device size in bytes (the same approach performed by `blockdev(8)`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <linux/fs.h>

int main(void) {
        int fd = 0;
        unsigned long long size = 0;

        if (getuid() != 0) {
                puts("You need to be root.");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if ((fd = open("/dev/loop0", O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
                printf("open(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (ioctl(fd, BLKGETSIZE64, &size) < 0) {
                printf("ioctl(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("%llu\n", size);

        return 0;
}
```

> **EDIT**:
>
> As discussed in comments, this is the `device level information`, so
>   if the file system does not *map* the entire device size, it won't solve
>   the problem (we still won't know the total size that the file system
>   occupy in the device).

.

## An attempt for a portable solution :)

I'm afraid you'll really, really need to do everything *by hand*, *step by step*.

You'll need to know the exact file system, understand its structure, and do all the math. For instance, in your example, you're using a 20MiB Ext2 filesystem. So, the structure will look like this (simplifying for the sake of the example):

> **Block 0**:
>
> - Boot record and extra boot record data: **1 block** (2 * 512 bytes)

.

> **Block Group 0**:
>
> - Superblock: **1 block** (1024 bytes)
> - Block Group Descriptor Table, Block Bitmap and Inode Bitmap: **3 blocks**
> - Inode Table: **214 blocks**
>
>   ... data blocks ...

.

> **Block Group 1**:
>
> - Superblock (backup): **1 block**
> - Block Group Descriptor Table (backup), Block Bitmap and Inode Bitmap: **3 blocks**
> - Inode Table: **214 blocks**
>
>   ... data blocks ...

.

> **Block Group 2**:
>
> - Block Bitmap and Inode Bitmap: **2 blocks**
> - Inode Table: **214 blocks**
>
>   ... data blocks ...

.

> **Now by doing the math**:
>
> - 1 + 1 + 3 + 214 + 1 + 3 + 214 + 2 + 214 == **653**
>
> Sum **653** to **19827** (which you can retrieve with `statvfs(2)`):
>
> - 653 + 19827 == **20480 blocks**

**EDIT 2**:

As discussed in comments, the ext2 superblock `block count` already contains the **total blocks** occupied by the file system (not only the usable blocks as I previously thought). A simple test to observe it (skipped error checking for the simplicity [of the example]):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

struct ext2_super_block {
        uint32_t        s_inodes_count;
        uint32_t        s_blocks_count;
        uint32_t        s_r_blocks_count;
        uint32_t        s_free_blocks_count;
        uint32_t        s_free_inodes_count;
        uint32_t        s_first_data_block;
        uint32_t        s_log_block_size;
        uint32_t        s_dummy3[7];
        unsigned char   s_magic[2];
        uint16_t        s_state;
        uint32_t        s_dummy5[8];
        uint32_t        s_feature_compat;
        uint32_t        s_feature_incompat;
        uint32_t        s_feature_ro_compat;
        unsigned char   s_uuid[16];
        char            s_volume_name[16];
        char            s_last_mounted[64];
        uint32_t        s_algorithm_usage_bitmap;
        uint8_t         s_prealloc_blocks;
        uint8_t         s_prealloc_dir_blocks;
        uint16_t        s_reserved_gdt_blocks;
        uint8_t         s_journal_uuid[16];
        uint32_t        s_journal_inum;
        uint32_t        s_journal_dev;
        uint32_t        s_last_orphan;
        uint32_t        s_hash_seed[4];
        uint8_t         s_def_hash_version;
        uint8_t         s_jnl_backup_type;
        uint16_t        s_reserved_word_pad;
        uint32_t        s_default_mount_opts;
        uint32_t        s_first_meta_bg;
        uint32_t        s_mkfs_time;
        uint32_t        s_jnl_blocks[17];
        uint32_t        s_blocks_count_hi;
        uint32_t        s_r_blocks_count_hi;
        uint32_t        s_free_blocks_hi;
        uint16_t        s_min_extra_isize;
        uint16_t        s_want_extra_isize;
        uint32_t        s_flags;
        uint16_t        s_raid_stride;
        uint16_t        s_mmp_interval;
        uint64_t        s_mmp_block;
        uint32_t        s_raid_stripe_width;
        uint32_t        s_reserved[163];
};

int main(void) {
        int fd = 0;
        struct ext2_super_block sb;

        /* Reset sb memory */
        memset(&sb, 0, sizeof(struct ext2_super_block));

        /*
         * /tmp/loop.img created with:
         *
         * dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=20480 of=/tmp/loop.img
         *
         * ... and the ext2 file system maps the entire device.
         *
         */
        fd = open("/tmp/loop.img", O_RDONLY);

        /* Jump to superblock */
        lseek(fd, 1024, SEEK_SET);

        /* Read the superblock */
        read(fd, &sb, sizeof(struct ext2_super_block));

        /* Print the total block count */
        printf("s_blocks_count: %" PRIu32 "\n", sb.s_blocks_count); /* Prints 20480 */

        return 0;
}
```

.

## Some final thoughts

- Doing it by hand is just crazy, IMO (you must have a very, very good reason to do so :)) [**EDIT 2**]: It's simpler than I previously thought, as [probably] all the filesystems superblock [may] contain the total block count (see this answer comments for related discussion).
- If I were you, I would evaluate in how many different operating systems *that piece of code* is supposed to run, and just implement the device level information gatherers with the non-portable calls (being them direct system calls [if any] or library implementations) provided by each operating system. Then, the building process would be able to determine and configure the code to properly compile on the target machine [**EDIT 2**]: This still is the best approach (making use of the respective file system libraries).
- If you really don't want (or need) to code anything and you're just looking for a Linux-specific command-line tool to retrieve such data (at device level), go with: `blockdev --getsize64 /dev/loop0` [**EDIT 2**]: This is device level information and it's not what the question refers to.
- [**EDIT**] Otherwise, if the device level information isn't enough (in the case the file system only *maps* a portion of the device size), you already have the answer: do with `dumpe2fs`, `tune2fs` and alike.

Comment: `the non-portable calls provided by each operating system` you point to are, unfortunately, the wrong ones: querying the size of a loop device or of a partition/block device doesn't help, if the file system doesn't cover the whole device/partition.

Comment: Yes, that's true. So, basically, if you want to cover that case too, you'll need to calculate the file system overhead by hand based on its structure...

Comment: The file-system-specific way to calculate the file system size is much simpler, actually: most (if not all) file systems have the size encoded in their superblock. See https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/blob/master/lib/blkid/probe.h

Comment: I don't think ext2 (at least) contains a field in the superblock structure indicating the total blocks (only the total `free`+`used`+`reserved(root)`). But yes, to properly obtain the data for `fs` calculations, you'll always need to read it from the superblock, as there's no other way. But I don't think it'd be possible without calculating the blocks [free, usable, reserved, and meta] for each block group.

Comment: I've just tested it, and you're right. The `s_block_count` contains the total blocks (in the question example, it reads as 20480 blocks). I'll update the answer with that.